# Convergence in $C[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $X_n = nt^n$.   Show that $\{X_n\}$ has no limit in $C[0,1]$.

My attempt to solve this problem is shown below.

$$\|X_n \|_\infty = \max⁡|X_n(t)|.$$ 
But I have no idea how to proceed from there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Note that $X_n(t)$ is not uniformly convergent over $[0,1]$ since $$X_n(1)=n\to \infty$$